# Select "empty" records excluded by WHERE clause

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a set of data from a view that looks something like this (*simplified*):

```
+-------------+-------------+------------+ 
| PartnerCode | ReportMonth | MonthTotal |
+-------------+-------------+------------+
| AMG         | 200912      |   100000   |
+-------------+-------------+------------+
| OSC         | 202009      |    10000   |
+-------------+-------------+------------+
| OSC         | 202010      |    15000   |
+-------------+-------------+------------+
| SSI         | 202009      |   200000   |
+-------------+-------------+------------+
| SSI         | 202010      |   250000   |
+-------------+-------------+------------+
```

From this data, I want to query the totals for each **`PartnerCode`** in the **`ReportMonth`** of `202010`. Straightforward enough, but I ***ALSO*** want to include an "empty" record for any **`PartnerCode`** that doesn't have a record for that **`ReportMonth`**. I'm not sure why this is stumping me so badly, but I can't seem to get it right. I've tried several variations, including the following:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
    "pa"."PartnerCode",
    COALESCE("pv"."MonthTotal", 0::numeric(11,2)) AS "MonthTotal"
FROM "PartnerTotalView" "pa"
LEFT JOIN "PartnerTotalView" "pv" ON "pv"."PartnerCode" = "pa"."ParnterCode"
WHERE "pv"."ReportMonth"=202010
```

While this gets the correct values for the two **`PartnerCode`** rows with a matching **`ReportMonth`**, it doesn't include the row with a **`PartnerCode`** of `AMG`:

```
+-------------+------------+ 
| PartnerCode | MonthTotal |
+-------------+------------+
| OSC         |    15000   |
+-------------+------------+
| SSI         |   250000   |
+-------------+------------+
```

I was expecting the query to pick up all of the values in the `pa` set that should include ALL of the rows in the original view, then `LEFT JOIN` it with the "filtered" rows so that anything that didn't match would have a `NULL` value in the **`MonthTotal`** column (*hence the `COALESCE`*). I've also tried pulling data from the original sources for the view in various ways to get what I'm looking for. What I would LIKE to see is the following:

```
+-------------+------------+ 
| PartnerCode | MonthTotal |
+-------------+------------+
| AMG         |        0   |
+-------------+------------+
| OSC         |    15000   |
+-------------+------------+
| SSI         |   250000   |
+-------------+------------+
```

I *have* been able to successfully get what I'm looking for by jumping through some additional hoops with subqueries:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
    "pa"."PartnerCode",
    (SELECT
        (COALESCE("t"."MonthTotal", 0::numeric(11,2))
    FROM "PartnerTotalView" "t"
    WHERE "t"."ReportMonth" = 202010
    AND "t"."PartnerCode" = "pa"."PartnerCode") AS "MonthTotal"
FROM "PartnerTotalView" "pa"
```

However, the performance of this method is significantly slower. I'm certain I'm just overlooking something simple, but I'm at a loss for what that could be.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: you should really avoid those dreaded quoted identifiers. They are much more trouble than they are worth it. https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names

Comment: Move the "pv"."ReportMonth" condition from WHERE to ON if you want true LEFT JOIN result. As it is now, you'll get regular INNER JOIN result.

Comment: Thank you @a_horse_with_no_name . I realize they can be "troublesome", but I've been working with data structures that were originally built using them. At this point, it's more trouble to eliminate them than to just get used to using them. ;)

Comment: Thank you for the information, @jarlh. That is indeed what I'm seeing (`INNER JOIN` behavior instead of `LEFT JOIN`), but don't understand *why* it behaves that way, which is what prompted my question. I did as you suggested and it does seem to produce the "correct" results, so I appreciate the assistance.

Comment: It *behaves that way* because inner join and outer join mean *semantically different things*. Inner joins says return rows from both tables which match the specified condition, left (outer) joins says the same, but also rows from the left mentioned table that have no rows matching the condition in the right, with null values for each column right mentioned table. (Note: This is the simplified version see [left join or left outer join](https://www.w3resource.com/PostgreSQL/postgresql-left-join.php) for fuller description that includes Right and Full outer joins.

Comment: Thank you, @Belayer, but that doesn't quite answer the question of "why" for this particular query. I was trying to use the `LEFT JOIN` syntax to get all the rows in the table (`pa`), regardless of whether there was a matching row with the specific `MonthReported` selection (`pv`). The `WHERE` clause, in this case, seems to negate that behavior, which is what was confusing me. By moving the `WHERE` condition into the `LEFT JOIN ON` clause, it seems to work as expected.

Comment: Sorry misses that. Yes a WHERE condition on any column in  the right side table in a left join essentially makes it a inner join. This is because that every column on the right listed table in NULL. In this particular case "pv"."ReportMonth" is NULL then the on condition is not satisfied. You could use ("pv"."ReportMonth"=202010 or "pv"."ReportMonth" is null) to get non matched rows.

Comment: Thank you, @Belayer. That helps to clear it up. Perhaps I'm simply being dense, but it's starting to make more sense in my mind. I definitely appreciate the follow-up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method is aggregation:

```
SELECT "pa"."PartnerCode",
       SUM(CASE WHEN "t"."MonthTotal" = 202010 THEN "t"."MonthTotal" ELSE 0 END) as MonthTotal
FROM "PartnerTotalView" "pa"
GROUP BY "pa"."PartnerCode"
```